# Algorithm for finding a bounded image

Tags: image, algorithm, bounds

what would be the most effective and efficient algorithm for finding a solid-color bounded image (an image within a border, for example) given a one-dimensional array of pixel values and a threshold?

I thought of a couple.
For example:
Start at the halfway point of the image dimensions e.g. width / 2 height / 2.
loop through pixels until you hit a pixel not in your threshold. Do this for all four sides and extract dimensions from the indexes.
The problem with this algorithm is if you are given an image that is, for example, only bounded on the right side, and its width is less than half of the containing image... then this wouldn't work.

```
public static Rect GetBounded(this WriteableBitmap wb, int aRGBThreshold)
{
    int[] pixels = wb.Pixels;
    int width = wb.PixelWidth;
    int height = wb.PixelHeight;

    int leftIndex = (height / 2) * width;
    int topIndex = width / 2;
    int rightIndex = (width * (height / 2 + 1)) - 1;
    int bottomIndex = width * height - (width / 2);
    int left = 0, top = 0, right = 0, bottom = 0;

    int i;
    for (i = leftIndex; i <= rightIndex; i++)
    {
        if (pixels[i] < aRGBThreshold)
            break;
        left++;
    }
    for (i = topIndex; i <= bottomIndex; i += width)
    {
        if (pixels[i] < aRGBThreshold)
            break;
        top++;
    }
    for (i = rightIndex; i >= leftIndex; i--)
    {
        if (pixels[i] < aRGBThreshold)
            break;
        right++;
    }
    for (i = bottomIndex; i >= topIndex; i -= width)
    {
        if (pixels[i] < aRGBThreshold)
            break;
        bottom++;
    }

    return new Rect(left, top, width - right - left, height - bottom - top);
}

public static Rect GetBounded(this WriteableBitmap wb, int aThreshold, int rThreshold, int gThreshold, int bThreshold)
{
    int argbthreshold = (aThreshold << 24) + (rThreshold << 16) + (gThreshold << 8) + bThreshold;
    return wb.GetBounded(argbthreshold);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Is the object of interest always a rectangle, as in your example, or its shape is arbitrary?

Comment: @ChronoTrigger that is a good question (and an awesome game), I guess I should make the constraint an arbitrary shape? I am not sure to be certain I may need this for an arbitrary shape in the future. Would it be harder to write/less efficient for an arbitrary shape?

Comment: If the shape is constrained, you can always think of an algorithm that fits better. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case you are looking for a rectangle (as your approach and code suggest), your approach is good. You could improve it by doing a binary search instead of a linear one to find the first and last object points in a row or column. This is similar to the c++ functions `std::lower_bound` and `std::upper_bound` (see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm). This should be faster if your rectangles are far away from the image boundaries.

If the object can have any shape but its components are connected, probably it would be better to find a single pixel that lies in the object and do [flood fill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) later.

If the object can have any shape and does not need to be connected, you have to traverse the whole image and keep the minimum and maximum row and column where the pixel exceeds the threshold. I think it would be enough to scan rows only, from left until you find an object pixel and from right later. If the image is stored in row-major order, it is more efficient to scan rows. If it is in column-major order, scan columns.